# C program to get average of 2 numbers in a 16 bit processor

Tags: c, embedded, overflow

How do we write a program in C which can calculate an average of 2 16 bit signed numbers on a 16 bit processor.

```
int getAverage(int x, int y)
{
   int result=0;
   result = ((x+y)/2);
   return result;
}
```

The above works for most cases except for when both x and y are max values 65535.

Comment: It doesn't work whenever x+y > 32767 (or < -32768), which is a lot of cases.

Comment: But the solution is just to use an `int32_t` for the intermediate calculation.

Comment: Divide by parts such as hi(8bit) and low(8bit) and try computing on them (promoting all four of them to 16 bit ofcourse) check for overflows and etc. But dealing with sign can be trick.

Comment: Hint: (x+y)/2 = x/2 + y/2. Well, in integer case you might want to add 1 if x and y are odd...

Comment: *"The above works for most cases except for when both x and y are max values 65535."* 65535 is not within the range of 16-bit signed numbers.

Comment: The important factor is not what the width of the ALU is, but rather what your compiler considers the range of an `int` to be.  Of course, most compilers have data types larger than their int available anyway, and if not they can always be extended by libraries which perform operations in parts.

Comment: Using long int is the simplest way, I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case where both x and y are positive or negative numbers, I would divide the difference between the numbers by 2 and add that result to the number that is subtracted. Mathematically, this is equivalent to what you currently have:

(y - x)/2 + x = y/2 - x/2 + x = y/2 + x/2 = (x + y)/2

If x is positive and y is negative or vice versa, the original method of calculation that you have should be used.

Comment: The previous deleted answer `return x/2 + y/2 + (x%2 + y%2)/2;` worked

Comment: @WeatherVane: Yes, I deleted it, as still something is wrong. For instance with `x = 3` and `y = -4`, there is clearly `-1/2`, that is zero. But `3/2 - 4/2 + (3%2 - 4%2)/2 = 1 - 2 + (1 - 0)/2 = -1 + 1/2 = -1 + 0 = -1`.

Comment: The averaging downwards can be fixed with an 'if'.

Comment: I like this solution. I was looking for a way to round it down too. Your above solution takes care of that too. Thanks,

Comment: If you implement this in practice, it will most likely be far slower than converting the integers to 32 bit. All these divisions cannot easily be optimized away by the compiler, and division tends to be a speed bottleneck on smaller CPUs.

Comment: There is only 1 division per function call.

Comment: @tim Ok if you say so, you posted no code so I just imagined things :) This is probably the very same answer as my own, come to think of it.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest possible solution with some crude integer rounding:

```
int32_t getAverage (int16_t x, int16_t y)
{
   int32_t sum = (int32_t)x + (int32_t)y;
   return sum/2 + sum%2;
}
```

This will work just fine since your 16 bit compiler will have software routines to handle 32 bit integers.

Comment: I like this approach because the intention can be clearly discerned in the future.  Not sure the rounding is a requirement though.